# Were there early signs Pat liked Kat?

Tags: character, 10-things-i-hate-about

In the movie *10 things I Hate About You*, it becomes very obvious after the party scene where Kat gets drunk that Pat is at least somewhat into her, taking care of her physically and not taking advantage of her in her drunken state.

Were there any signs previous to this scene that Pat actually liked Kat?

Answer (score 6):

The only indication I can find of 'liking' that's not clearly influenced by the financial incentive is when he's watching Kat dancing in the club.

She doesn't know he's there and it sure looks like *appreciation* at the very least.

[image]

Whether that's "liking" under the description in your question is open to interpretation....but it doesn't look forced or 'incentivised' to me.